# Ruby on Rails How to inject values from controller inside coffeescript

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, coffeescript

I've got controller on the back-end, and want to have variables inside (coffee)script which send with mockup to browser - but got undifined values. what I'm doing wrong? I could see values in mockup.

contoller:

```
def show
    @article = Article.find(params[:id])
end
```

Script article.coffee.erb:

```
$ ->
      $('#sendComment').click ->
        id = "#{@article.id}"
        console.log(id)
```

in mockup:

```
%p
  %strong Title:
  #id
  = @article.id
%p
  %strong Title:
  = @article.title
```

Comment: Where and how is *article.coffee.erb* being loaded? Where is `#sendComment`? Instead of *mockup* tell us where are you rendering that HAML?

Comment: @Leito  it's already on page when it loaded - rails added it where like script

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The front-end code is parsed by browser and is not aware of the server-side code in controllers. The assets are compiled once and won't change on different requests. What you need to do is to add the article id in the HTML tag, and then fetch it in your JS code:

```
<%= tag.p data: { "article-id": @article.id } %>
```

then in JS:

```
$('p').click( (event) ->
  id = $(event.target).data('article-id')
  console.log(id)
)
```

It's not clear where is `#sendComment` in your view code so I changed it to `p` here. But the point is clear anyway.

Comment: It's look better but problem that in mockup after I used haml converter it's look like this : 
<p data-article-id="11"></p>

Comment: @FridmanChan That's the correct behavior. the `.data()` function on jquery is for getting the `data` attributes from the html tags: https://api.jquery.com/data/

Answer (score 0):

if `@article` is a controller variable you need to use `<%= @article.id %>` erb interpolation to get the value from the controller.

```
$ ->
      $('#sendComment').click ->
        id = "<%= @article.id %>" # instead of "#{@article.id}" which is the CoffeeScript String interpolation. 
        console.log(id)
```

Comment: Not work. if I write exactly like you send - its error : undefined method `id' for nil:NilClass . It means that @article still empty

Comment: @FridmanChan what is the url that you're using to access make sure that the article you're tying to access it's actually there in the DB.

Comment: I could see this id on mockup.100% its in DB